# Rails google analytics insufficientPermissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I use gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2' and want get infromation from google analytics, my omniauth file have:

```
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV['google_key'], ENV['google_secret'], {scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics', access_type: 'offline', select_account: true}
```

but I have error:

```
{"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"insufficientPermissions", "message"=>"Insufficient Permission"}], "code"=>403, "message"=>"Insufficient Permission"}: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "insufficientPermissions", "message": "Insufficient Permission" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Insufficient Permission" } }
```

I enabled google analytics in developer console. Who can help me?

Comment: What API request are you making? Are you request to access to account, property or view (profile) for which you do not have permission to access? Or are you using a service account and failed to add the service account to  the account, property and view (profile).

Comment: I need get uniq users who view my profile in google analytics

Comment: I fixed it, but I can`t get analitics datas

Comment: Play around with the query explorer: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ to construct the proper pramaters you are trying to request. Then use those same parameters in your ruby code. Perhaps you requested a date range which contains no data?

Comment: You need tokens with sufficient permissions. Your app needs to request tokens using key and secret.